# C++ User-defined names for keys/values of map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

When iterating through a map (or unordered_map) in c++, the keys and values are accessed through .first and .second. But is there a way to access the key/value pairs in a more semantically meaningful way?

As an example, if I store an algebraic expression in a map< set, int> as:

```
x - 2yz + 3xyz  -->  expr = { {{'x'}, 1}, {{'y','z'}, -2}, {{'x','y','z'}, 3} }
```

and I want to iterate through the map, it seems very natural to want to do:

```
for(auto & term : expr)
    term.vars ...
    term.coeff ...
```

instead of

```
for(auto & term : expr)
    term.first ...
    term.second ...
```

Is there any way to achieve this with a `struct Term { set<char> vars; int coeff; };`? I can't see any way to integrate such a struct with map, but I also can't think of any fundamental reasons why it should be impossible, since for e.g. it's trivial in python: `[(vars,coeff) for vars,coeff in expr.items()]`.

Comment: If C++17 is not an option, there's always std::tie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `c++17` is available to you then you can use `structured bindings` to decompose the pair

```
for (auto [vars, coeff] : expr) { ... }
```

without changing anything else.

If you can not use `c++17` then your `Term` struct can be used in a `std::vector` or another `sequence container` as you have taken away the associativity and put it in the struct itself.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Btw I didn't want to put it in a vector because I would lose the fast lookup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use structured binding:

```
for (auto & [vars, coeff]: expr) {
    f(vars);
    g(coeff);
}
```

This requires C++17.